# restart a java swing application

Tags: java, swing

I am a fresher and I have created a java swing application, which is running perfectly.

I want to add a functionality in this application that when user exit or close this application from anywhere like close from task manager, or force stop or by some other methods. Application will restart automatically after some time.

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: You can define your app to hide on close.
When you talk about a restart after a forced closing dont you think it will be quite anoying?

Comment: You want to run in wich OS?

Comment: You can set up a scheduled job to start the application. Use scheduler for windows or crontab for linux based Systems.

Comment: want to run on mac OS

Answer (score 0):

```
    new java.util.Timer().schedule(
    new java.util.TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final String javaBin = System.getProperty("java.home") + File.separator + "bin" + File.separator + "java";
            final File currentJar = new File(MyClassInTheJar.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI());

            /* is it a jar file? */
            if(!currentJar.getName().endsWith(".jar"))
            return;

            /* Build command: java -jar application.jar */
            final ArrayList<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
            command.add(javaBin);
            command.add("-jar");
            command.add(currentJar.getPath());

            final ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
            builder.start();
            System.exit(0);                                     
        }
    },
    5000);
```

read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: So how is this code restarting his application? It only tells the JVM to shutdown.

Comment: @SurfMan: but before that is spawns a new Java process running your application.

Comment: yes, restart process perform two step: stop and start. above code block achive same thing. 
privous jvm instance stop and new jvm instance up.

Comment: Funny how my earlier comment does not make sense after @Hardik edited his code example. His first version contained only System.exit(0) wrapped in a Timer.